# Lubuntu CUPS Question: How to solve "Printer drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of CUPS."

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, printing

I am a relatively new Linux user. I use Lubuntu 22.04, and I am enjoying Linux so far.

CUPS is up to date and I can access it through localhost, I have also installed the appropriate drivers from the Epson website and added my printer, which is an Epson L3110, to CUPS

I tried `lp` command and got an error in /var/log/cups/error_log:

> Printer drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of CUPS. See https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups/issues/103

I have looked into that Github link but got lost, what am I to do? The link mentioned PAPPL and what looks like [a really technical tutorial on how to build printer drivers](https://openprinting.github.io/documentation/02-designing-printer-drivers/). Should I go and do this? Would following this tutorial solve my issue? Or is there a better way maybe?

Comment: The warning message you quoted has nothing whatsoever to do with whether you can print or not. Forget about it and reveal your connection method. USB? Now give the output of `lpinfo -v`.

Comment: @brian_p sorry for the late reply! Would understand if you won't read this, connection method is USB, lpinfo gives this: network ipp
network beh
network lpd
network http
network https
file cups-brf:/
network socket
serial serial:/dev/ttyS0?baud=115200
direct hp
network ipps
direct usb://EPSON/L3110%20Series?serial=583933503238373979&interface=1
direct hpfaxl

Answer (score 0):

My printer (Samsung ML-1630 under Kubuntu 22.04) refused printing and gave by investigation some cryptic error message: "Failed to create /var/spool/cups/tmp/.hplip". Further Google-results were even more dire: "Printer drivers are deprecated and will stop working in a future version of CUPS".

Problem got solved today with two clicks by using the GUI system dialogue to select the still supported printer driver of the previous model (Samsung FL 1610-foomatic/gdi). Printer is now up and running again.